# Can't figure out iPad landscape view coordinates

Tags: xcode, ipad, xcode4

Being new to objective-C but tinkering I was trying out dragging with the iPad, and the following code from my viewcontroller.m works okay in portrait, but not in landscape:

```
-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {    
UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:mainView.superview];
testViewToMove.center = location;
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
[self touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

mainView being the default view that was created with the app, and testViewToMove being a UIView I made for kicks.

In landscape, the coordinates don't seem to translate. I'm sure this is something obvious, but I don't get it, what's going on here?

I tried setting the view to landscape, and tinkering with some other settings to no avail... I also saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/896994/is-there-a-way-to-convert-the-coordinate-system-after-a-change-to-landscape-orien), but to my own dismay I haven't been able to get it to work.

Comment: Well, the answer provided in that other question you mention really should solve your problem. What exactly is giving you trouble implementing that code?

Comment: Tweaking at it with fresh eyes, it seems to be working now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems I just needed to change *mainView.superview* to *self.view* in the first method, after applying the fix linked above.